# jQuery mobile specific list

Tags: jquery, list, mobile, jquery-mobile

Is there a list on jQuery mobile to produce something like this:

[image]

I searched some sites, but haven't found anything related.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breadcrumbs are not found in jQuery Mobile but can be found in jQuery plugins, for example:

http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html
http://www.ajaxblender.com/script-sources/xbreadcrumbs/demo/index.html

Comment: Can you check this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/2dqFK/1/ It doesn't work, can figure why.

Comment: you'll need to add the jBreadCrumb library to you jsFiddle to work

Comment: I added it after the easing part

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2dqFK/3/ seems to work as expected.

Comment: updated jsFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/2dqFK/4/ ... now it works as in documentation page