# Breadcrumb for Mobile Page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery Mobile for building a mobile website, now I have to put a breadcrumb for each steps in the pageflow. With small screen (only 4 inch), I have no idea for this one.

Do you guys have any ideas for putting the breadcrumb into mobile web page, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links that u can used to put breadcrumb in your site

[jQuery mobile specific list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563874/jquery-mobile-specific-list)

http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html

http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/05/css-breadcrumb-separators-with.html

[CSS overlapping arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075116/css-overlapping-arrow)

and for your small screen (only 4 inch) you can set css according to your convenience.

I Hope these may help you.